# Vitamio not work in Cpu Intel?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

We in the house, so a player nexus Intel CPU, and a shield nvidia tv.
Vitamio in nexus player screen remains black, in nvidia go, but not all, but the nexus 6 oneplus one works perfectly.
In zenfone asus, intel cpu screen remains black again.
Vitamio is not compatible with Intel? or NVIDIA?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
public class Utv extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String path;
    //private HashMap<String, String> options;
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
            return;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_utv);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);
        path = "http://80.86.107.169:8100/stream.flv";
        /*options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("rtmp_playpath", "");
        options.put("rtmp_swfurl", "");
        options.put("rtmp_live", "1");
        options.put("rtmp_pageurl", "");*/
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        //mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path), options);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```